# Datatype time MySQL vs aspx page in cs

Tags: c#, mysql

On MySQL table it's memorize this value on column `sTime` datatype time (HH:mm:ss)

```
24:20:34
```

This value is a time difference between two start and end dates

```
2020-06-19 23:11:10 Start date 
2020-06-20 23:31:44 End date
```

For recovery this value `24:20:34` on aspx page I have inserted

```
tx2.Text = reader["sTime"].ToString().ToUpper();
```

But the return on the browser is

```
1.00:21:00
```

I have tried without success

```
    DateTime HHMMSS = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["sTime"]);
    tx2.Text = HHMMSS.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me, please?

**update**

```
    TimeSpan diff = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndDate"]) - 
                    Convert.ToDateTime(reader["StartDate"]);
```

return

```
1.00:21:00
```

Comment: Why it is 24:21:00 and not 00:21:00?

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk the format is HH:mm:ss. Is a time difference between two start and end dates

Comment: You are aware that MySql has Date and Time data types and you do not have to create problems by storing times as strings?

Comment: Have a look at TimeSpan, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @TomTom thanks I have changed datatype in column `sTime` from `time` to `varchar` and now working. But it's a solution?

Comment: @Donal please see **update** in question